# select a value from telerik ddl using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

Is there a way to select a value from telerik ddl using jquery?

Here is my Telerik DDL:

```
        <%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("Quarter")
           .Items(items => {
            items.Add().Text("").Value("");
            items.Add().Text("Quarter1").Value("Quarter1");
            items.Add().Text("Quarter2").Value("Quarter2");
            items.Add().Text("Quarter3").Value("Quarter3");
            items.Add().Text("Quarter4").Value("Quarter4");
                })%>
```

I am trying the following way, but its doesnt populate the list:

```
$("#Quarter").val("Quarter2");
```

Rendered HTML for Telerik DDL after selecting value:

```
<div tabIndex="0" class="t-widget t-dropdown t-header" id="Quarter" style="width: 104px;" jQuery15103337264984743067="21" value="Quarter2">
  <div class="t-dropdown-wrap t-state-default">
    <span class="t-input">
      Text - Quarter 2
    <span class="t-select">
      <span class="t-icon t-arrow-down">
  <input name="Quarter" id="Quarter" style="display: none;" type="text"/>
```

Comment: How does the Rendered HTML look like??

Comment: You should use each() function..

Comment: @Sushanth-- I've updated my question with the rendered HTML

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/combobox/combo_client_model.html

I think the problem is that Telerik doesn't even have a hidden `<select>` to work with (which `.val()` would be how you'd normally select the value), so you have to use their (cough) stupid methodology to do it. I for one absolutely hate putting any back-end .NET code in front-end JS

Looks like with Telerik you'd have to do something like:

**FindItemByValue** : Returns the first RadComboBoxItem object whose Value property is equal to the passed parameter.

```
// Also it doesn't look like your giving your DDL an ID
var combo = <%=RadComboBox1.ClientID %>; // ClientID being whatever your ID is

combo.FindItemByValue("Quarter2");
// or
combo.SetValue("Quarter2");
```

Comment: Its not a RadComboBox its a normal Telrik DDL. Also, if ClientID is the ID of my DDL what is RadComboBox1 id of?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
var value = $('#Quarter').data('tDropDownList').value();
```